# gerate random token to user in laravel

Tags: laravel

on a site I'm trying to develop with a token, give me back this error, I've tried surfing the internet for solutions but so far nothing:\

If someone can help me thank you.

```
(1/1) Error
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\str_random()
in UserController.php line 65
at UserController->doRegisto(object(Request))


else {
            Session::flash('message', "Este email está disponivel.");
        $user = new User;

        $user->nome = $request->nome;
        $user->morada = $request->morada;
        $user->distrito = $request->distrito;
        $user->cod_postal = $request->cod_postal;
        $user->localidade = $request->localidade;
        $user->nif = $request->nif;
        $user->telefone = $request->telefone;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user->save();


        $verificar = new verificar_user;
        $token = str_random(32);
        $verificar->id_user = $user->id;
        $verificar->token = $token;

        $data = ['token' => $token];
```

Comment: What Laravel version?

Comment: If it's laravel 6 I correctly marked it as duplicate. str_ function where removed

Comment: Latest Laravel versions no longer include helper methods by default. You need to manually install the package with `composer require laravel/helpers`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
$token = Str::random(32);
```

Let me know if it help you!

Comment: ok now works what i try this one time but dont work, thank you so

Comment: it did't work ?

Comment: yes did works!!